# How do I read python core dumps?

Tags: python, macos, pandas, segmentation-fault, lldb

I have a python program, that is intermittently dumping core. I'd like to know where it's seg-faulting, but I'm not sure how to figure that out.

When I run with pdb, it just crashes, and says exit 11, because (I assume) that the proximate cause of the seg-fault is that python itself is crashing. (a python program shouldn't seg-fault, is my understanding) It looks like it's crashing in pandas...

When I look at the core, in lldb (I'm on a mac) I get:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x0000, 0x0000000103bac575 lib.so`__pyx_pw_6pandas_3lib_107count_level_2d + 6757, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x0000000103bac575 lib.so`__pyx_pw_6pandas_3lib_107count_level_2d + 6757
    frame #1: 0x000000010000c612 Python`PyObject_Call + 98
    frame #2: 0x0000000102614621 _functools.so`partial_call + 129
    frame #3: 0x000000010000c612 Python`PyObject_Call + 98
    frame #4: 0x00000001025e3926 itertools.so`imap_next + 150
    frame #5: 0x000000010000c283 Python`PyIter_Next + 19
    frame #6: 0x00000001025e38eb itertools.so`imap_next + 91
    frame #7: 0x0000000100047cc7 Python`listextend + 199
    frame #8: 0x0000000100048297 Python`list_init + 215
    frame #9: 0x0000000100075e45 Python`type_call + 245
    frame #10: 0x000000010000c612 Python`PyObject_Call + 98
    frame #11: 0x00000001000bf3bc Python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 7996
    frame #12: 0x00000001000c58e3 Python`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
    frame #13: 0x00000001000c3655 Python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25045
    frame #14: 0x00000001000c58e3 Python`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
    frame #15: 0x00000001000c3655 Python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25045
    frame #16: 0x00000001000c58e3 Python`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
    frame #17: 0x00000001000c3655 Python`PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 25045
    frame #18: 0x00000001000c58e3 Python`PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 2115
    frame #19: 0x00000001000c5a06 Python`PyEval_EvalCode + 54
    frame #20: 0x00000001000ea41e Python`PyRun_FileExFlags + 174
    frame #21: 0x00000001000ea6ba Python`PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 458
    frame #22: 0x000000010010187d Python`Py_Main + 3101
    frame #23: 0x0000000100000f14 python
```

Which doesn't seem useful, possibly because I'm not running with symbols? (the equivalent of -g) I'm not sure.

I'd like to know what part of my code is causing this...

I'm using

- python 2.7
- pandas 0.18.0
- numpy 1.11.1
- scipy 0.17.0
- macOS 10.11.5

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, are you trying to view core data or find out where the seg fault is coming from? What exactly is your code trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, the eventual goal is to fix the segfault. But I figured that the initial step in that was to read the core dump.  If you have a better suggestion on the segfault, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code. Include the stack trace (if you get one).

Comment: Which part of the code? If I knew where in the code it was crashing, I'd be 50% there already... The thing I posted above, IS the stack trace. At least, it's the best I've gotten...

Comment: Looks like the call in frame 10 is the last call from your code, so you'd like to know what that call is.  You can do this by bisection, start adding prints in your python code, and use that to narrow down to the last statement you called before the crash.  Or you could try to examine the callable object passed to PyObject_Call or to the EvalFrameEx call proceeding it to see what that object is.  Truth to tell, you probably won't be able to do this in an optimized build of Python, since recovery of stack variables in optimized code is very iffy.

Comment: If you can, I'd get a debug build of Python (-g -O0) and see if you can get the crash there.  Then you should be able to see the objects being called, and poke at them to figure out what they are.